# $2 \int_a^b [f(x) \int_x^b f(y) dy] dx= [ \int_a^b f(x) dx] ^2$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

A hint on proving $2 \int_a^b [f(x)  \int_x^b f(y) dy] dx= [ \int_a^b f(x) dx] ^2$ would be much appreciated.

PS I couldn't made any progress so to write my attempt...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to the other answer but lets say $F'(x)=f(x)$ then:
$$2\int_a^bf(x)\int_x^bf(y)dydx=2\int_a^bf(x)[F(b)-F(x)]dx$$
If we break this up:
$$\int_a^bf(x)F(b)dx=F(b)[F(b)-F(a)]$$
now notice for the second integral we have something of the form $uu'$ so:
$$\int_a^bf(x)F(x)dx=\frac{F^2(b)-F^2(a)}{2}$$
now combine the two:
$$F(b)[F(b)-F(a)]-\frac{F^2(b)-F^2(a)}{2}=\frac{F^2(b)+F(a)[F(a)-2F(b)]}{2}$$
and multiplying by two gives us:
$$F^2(b)+F(a)[F(a)-2F(b)]=F^2(a)-2F(a)F(b)+F^2(a)$$
now lets have a look at the second part:
$$\left(\int_a^bf(x)dx\right)^2=\left(F(b)-F(a)\right)^2=F^2(b)-2F(a)F(b)+F^2(a)$$
so its true

Answer (score 0):

Write $F(x)$ for an anti-derivative of $f(x)$. By the fundamental theorem, the left hand side becomes $2\int_a^b f(x) (F(b)-F(x))\thinspace dy$. You can expand this to be $2\left(F(b)\int_a^bf(x)\thinspace dx -\int_a^b F(x)f(x)\thinspace dx \right)$. The remaining trick is to recognize that an antiderivative for $F(x)f(x)$ is $\frac{1}{2}F(x)^2$. Hope this helps.

Comment: The problem is that lower and upper variables are constant in the *first* integral so how do you use the fundamental theorem to insert derivative into the integeral?

Comment: I changed b to t (a variable) and it didn't work because again there is another t inside the middle integral

Comment: For all values of $x$, $\int_x^b f(y)\thinspace dy=F(b)-F(x)$, so you can safely replace the inner integral with this expression.